# How to use Protractor and browser.wait to give same results every time?

Tags: async-await, protractor

I'm using this in my end to end test:

```
//Ignore fit for now, I'm trying to resolve single issue, and I have 30ish tests in the file
  fit('Advanced search for ID should work', async function() {
        await browser.navigate().refresh();
        //Positioning on the right tab where serach works
        await attachmentHomepage.clickBtnRighTab();
        //Waiting for advanced search button to load on that tab
        await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(attachmentHomepage.btnAdvancedSearchToggle), 3000, 'waiting for button to be clickable');
        //Clicking it and opening hamburger like menu on the left side of the screen (which, if I click anywhere looses the focus) 
        await attachmentHomepage.clickBtnAdvancedSearchToggle();
        await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(attachmentHomepage.inputAttachmentIDAdvancedSearch), 5000, 'waiting field to be clickable');
        //Waiting for the field in the menu (Pseudo element) to become available
        await attachmentHomepage.setAttachmentIDInAdvancedSearch('1333');
        await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(attachmentHomepage.btnAdvancedSearchApply), 5000, 'waiting button to be clickable');
        //--->>>  Waiting for apply button that is in the same advanced search hamburger menu <<<----
        await attachmentHomepage.clickBtnApply();
        await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(attachmentHomepage.tblMainDataTable), 5000, 'waiting for main data table to be "clickable"');
        await browser.sleep(1000);
        expect(await attachmentHomepage.returnFirstResult()).toEqual('1333');
    });
```

My problem here is - this works, but not every time.

Every now and then I have a feeling that browser.wait for btnAdvancedSearchApply simply does not work.

Every time I run test, it opens the hamburger thing, it fills in the searched ID, and then it seems like it clicks somewhere on the screen instead of waiting for the button, and hamburger menu closes, and test fails.

Not sure how to make it wait every single time and 100% works.

Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you have CSS animations going on and the button is not visible immediately? I experienced similar errors in that case

Comment: your code seems to be right. I would run the code in vscode with debug configuration line by line. This would give an idea which moment each line is considered done, and if there is anything else on the page to wait until going to the next line